SFMC SQL string to get records which are 90 days between TODAY and a date field
I'm having issues with a SFMC SQL string which should get records that's within the next  90 days from today and my date field (Check_In_Date__c). I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I thought this was the correct query.
WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c < dateadd(day, -90, GETDATE())

The record count was 0 even though I know there should be 80 records here.
I tried this query as well and the record count was still 0.
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, o.Check_In_Date__c, DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) = 2


90 days ahead of today or 90 days ago?

90 days ahead of today. So records where the check_in_date is less or equal to 90 days from today

Then don't you want WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c < dateadd(day, 90, GETDATE()) ie remove the negative

Thank you, I did try that but it's now pulling records which are before the date bracket. To clarify, I only want records which check_in_date 90 days from TODAY. So if today is 28/11/2024, I only want records that have a check in date between 28/11/2024 and 28/02/2025 (90 days)

So WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c >= GETDATE() AND o.Check_In_Date__c < dateadd(day, 90, GETDATE()) it's just simple logic

Double check if you really want 90 days or rather 3 months. Mostly, the month check is correct and people check days because they don't know how to check months.

Thank you, that logic worked the way I needed it to! @Charlieface

WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) less or equal to 90 days from today
